# Download TeXLive distribution with Windows security

Tags: texlive, windows

I'm having a big problem with downloading the TeXLive distribution, as Windows considers it a virus, and I've tried more than 20 ways to deactivate Windows security, but it didn't work. So what is the solution?

I use Windows 10, I don't use any other security software, and I use an administrator account.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure that you downloaded it from the official website?

Comment: yes, https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Community answer*

- According to the comments, the OP has a Windows tool called "SmartScreen" installed, see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-is-smartscreen-and-how-can-it-help-protect-me-1c9a874a-6826-be5e-45b1-67fa445a74c8).
- The OP had to remove the domain in question from the filter: "Finally, after 48 hours of work, I found it, I deleted SmartScreen Filter."

> When you use the new **Microsoft Edge**, **Microsoft Defender SmartScreen**
> helps you identify reported phishing and malware websites and also
> helps you make **informed decisions about downloads**. [...] **SmartScreen checks files** that you download from the web against a **list of reported malicious software sites** and programs known to be unsafe. If it finds a match, SmartScreen will **warn** you that the **download** has been **blocked** for your safety. SmartScreen also checks the files that you download against a **list of files that are well known** and downloaded by many people who use Internet Explorer. **If the file that you're downloading isn't on that list, SmartScreen will warn you.**

*(**bold** formatting done by me)*

Answer (score 3):

I can only surmise what happened, but I think that you downloaded the file and got an Information window like ,,Your computer was protected by Windows Defender".

I suppose that this is caused by the file not being signed. (with a cryptographic certificate)
This is a protection mechanism to prevent users downloading suspicious
software.

**Solution**: When the information window appears, click on the ,,More Info" (or similar) button. A Button named ,,Execute anyway" (or similar) will appear. Click on it.

Please note that my PC's language is not English (and I am not a Native Speaker), therefore I cannot give you the exact button descriptions.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't, after downloading the file, Windows tells you that "the file is malicious", then you press keep it anyway, but when you run the program - to decompress - it tells you that it is unsafe and gives you no choice but to exit.

Comment: It works for me. Did you execute the downloaded file as administrator?

Comment: Finally, after 48 hours of work, I found it, I deleted SmartScreen Filter.  You probably don't have a SmartScreen Filter on your computer, and that's the difference. Am thankful.

Comment: Nice to hear, thanks for the update!